# The Diagnostic Tools Failed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

When I start debugging .NET application, sometimes the Diagnostic Tools of VS 2015 Community fails.

[image]

The output window shows:

***Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).***

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: try run VS as admin. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Nope.

Comment: Are the VShub.exe an the Visual Studio Standard Collector Service running?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes, both are running.

Comment: here I'm out of ideas.  Ask it in the MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/home?forum=vsdebug&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc